# Переписать код с vb.net на с++.net

Tags: vb.net, c++

```
   Public Function GetBetween(ByRef strSource As String, ByRef strStart As String, ByRef strEnd As String, Optional ByRef startPos As Integer = 0) As String
    Dim iPos As Integer, iEnd As Integer, lenStart As Integer = strStart.Length
    Dim strResult As String = ""

    iPos = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, startPos)
    iEnd = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, iPos + lenStart)

    If iPos <> -1 AndAlso iEnd <> -1 Then
        strResult = strSource.Substring(iPos + lenStart, iEnd - (iPos + lenStart))
    End If
    Return strResult
End Function
```

**mvs 2008 winform** 
Пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы хоть бы "Пожалуйста" написали...

Comment: без проблем ча исправим =)

Comment: Лучше напишите, что именно не понятно.
Мы тут сидим не ради "значков")

Comment: да все непонятно мне нужно класс и тп для парсинга с хтмл кода данных например между <titel></titel> 
вот знакомый дал код на вб а я вб вообще не шарю

Comment: тогда советую начать изучать C++

Comment: Нет, тогда надо изучать VB, да только стоит ли? А Вы интуитивно попробуйте догадаться, что означают те или иные элементы VB. Можете книжки и справочники какие-то поднять. В общем, проявите активности и творческую жилку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не пойму в чём проблема, хотя если бы меня попросили переписать что-нибудь на VB, я бы тоже немного задумался. И кстати, если юзать .net, то лучше уж сразу на C#:

```
public string GetBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd, int startPos){
    int iPos, iEnd, lenStart = strStart.Length;
    string strResult = "";

    iPos = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, startPos);
    iEnd = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, iPos + lenStart);

    if(iPos != -1 & iEnd != -1){
        strResult = strSource.Substring(iPos + lenStart, iEnd - (iPos + lenStart));
    }
    return strResult;
}

public string GetBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd){
    return GetBetween(strSource, strStart, strEnd, 0);
}
```